# ランキングに同じユーザーの投稿を3つ以上表示させない方法

Tags: ruby

ある投稿サービスを作成しており、ランキングを作成するため、下記のような形で作成しました。

```
@post_array =
{:post=>838, 
  :count=>6,
  :rank=>1,
  :user_id=>14},
 {:post=>837,
  :count=>4,
  :rank=>2,
  :user_id=>5},
 {:post=>835.
  :count=>2,
  :rank=>3,
  :user_id=>14}

post = 投稿のID
count = 投稿についたlikeの数
rank = 順位
user_id = ユーザーのID
```

このランキングでは同じユーザーの投稿は上位3投稿までしか表示させないようにしたいのですが、どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

こんなメソッド（関数）を定義してみました。

```
def limit_by_user(post_array, maximum)
  memo = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = 0 }
  post_array
    .sort_by { |post| post[:rank] }
    .select { |post|
      user_id = post[:user_id]
      (memo[user_id] += 1) <= maximum
    }
end
```

以下は実行結果です。

```
@post_array = [
  {:post => 838, :count => 6, :rank => 1, :user_id => 14},
  {:post => 837, :count => 4, :rank => 2, :user_id => 5},
  {:post => 835, :count => 9, :rank => 3, :user_id => 14},
  {:post => 904, :count => 8, :rank => 4, :user_id => 14},
  {:post => 905, :count => 7, :rank => 5, :user_id => 14},
  {:post => 906, :count => 6, :rank => 6, :user_id => 5},
]

puts limit_by_user(@post_array, 3)

# 実行結果
{:post=>838, :count=>6, :rank=>1, :user_id=>14}
{:post=>837, :count=>4, :rank=>2, :user_id=>5}
{:post=>835, :count=>9, :rank=>3, :user_id=>14}
{:post=>904, :count=>8, :rank=>4, :user_id=>14}
{:post=>906, :count=>6, :rank=>6, :user_id=>5}
```

ただ、これらのデータがもしデータベースに格納されているのなら、RubyよりもSQLでフィルタリングした方が処理効率が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

railsに頼らず、各ユーザーの上位３件ずつを抽出した作業テーブルか何かを用意してからソートすれば良いのではないでしょうか？